# Как начать использовать React js в своих проектах?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Добрый день, нужна помощь знающих фронтенд разработчиков и гуру React. Понадобилось мне написать тут не сложное приложение по Android и IOS, безусловно выбор пал на React-Native. После нескольких недель изучения React - Redux все получилось.

Но теперь есть желание начать использовать React в своих проектах. Но как это делать я не могу понять, все крутится вокруг полноценных web-приложений, а не каких-то отдельных компонентов.
Допустим есть у меня проект, например на Drupal, пусть будет интернет магазин. И все работает там хорошо на jQuery, и на php. Суть работы jQuery как библиотеки понятна и прозрачна, я ее подключаю к проекту и использую там где мне это надо. Надо обновить корзину, обновляю; надо вывести форму регистрации вывожу. Все просто и все хорошо и красиво работает.

Суть вопроса как в эту концепцию вписать React? Т.е. например мне надо сделать обновление корзины на React. Мне получается надо у себя поставить node js, запустить create-react-app, установить babel, создать компонент cart. Сделать в нем всю логику кукую-нибудь, потом запустить bulid получившийся js файл я подключаю на странице? Потом я захотел сделать форму регистрации, все мне это делать по новой? и опять получившийся файл подгружать на странице регистрации?
Или я что-то упуская и не до понимаю? Или React нужен для создание серьезных веб приложений и все и в проекте его использовать не получится?
Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Для написания отдельных компонент на React в существующем приложении вовсе не обязательно ставить create-react-app, он необходим больше для быстрого старта при написания больших SPA-приложений. Babel тоже можно опустить при условии, что вы не будете использовать JSX, а будете все делать на чистом JS. Сами компоненты будут рендериться в заранее готовый селектор для них через *ReactDOM.render*. Вообще уже существует довольно много статей на эту тему, например [здесь](https://reactarmory.com/answers/how-to-integrate-react-into-existing-app)